# How to make jmeter while controller work

Tags: jmeter

I'm having trouble getting the while controller to work in jmeter.

I've a feeling that I read that it doesn't re-evalute user defined variables, so I am trying to use properties instead.

I start off by using a BSF assertion to set a property called keepLooping

```
${__setProperty(keepLooping, true)};
```

This seems to work as it enters the While controller with a condition of

```
${__property(keepLooping)}
```

But I cannot for the life of me get it to change that property to something else. I want it to change the property depending on the resulting text of an http request.

So I am using a Regular Expression Extractor to set a variable, which I can see is getting set. Then I am trying to use a BSF assertion to set the keepLooping property on the basis of the variable that I have set. I am using javascript as follows:

```
log.info("IM IN HERE");
log.info("props is "+props);
//log.info("props keep looping is  "+props["keepLooping"]);
if (${surveyRequired} == false){
    log.info("IM IN HERE 1A and props is "+props);
    ${__setProperty(keepLooping, true)};
    log.info("IM IN HERE 1B");
}
else {
    log.info("IM IN HERE 2A");  
    ${__setProperty(keepLooping, false)};
    log.info("IM IN HERE 2B");
}
```

I can't figure out how to set the property with javascript - I've tried several things. Can anyone help? Many thanks!

Also can anyone recommend a good resource that negotiates what seem to be the many 'quirks' of jmeter? Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

"I've a feeling that I read that it doesn't re-evalute user defined variables" -- I use JMeter 2.9 and it really does. I use user defined variable in order to count number of loops. It looks like: `${__javaScript(${MY_USER_DEFINED_VARIABLE}>0)}`. The only one annoying thing is that I have to get value of variable, increment it, cast to string (`toString()` in Groovy), and then put new value into `MY_USER_DEFINED_VARIABLE` (by using `vars.putObject("MY_USER_DEFINED_VARIABLE",localBSFVariable)`)

Answer (score 0):

Using vars.put or props.put will help, as explained in detailed in detail [in this jmeter thread.](http://jmeter.512774.n5.nabble.com/How-to-set-a-javascript-value-as-a-JMeter-property-td5577158.html)